# FooTable custom breakpoints not working

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, footable

I'm using Footable plugin. I've read about breakpoints in its [documentation](http://fooplugins.com/footable-jquery/documentation/) and [here](https://responsivedesign.is/resources/data-tables/footable).
I can set custom breakpoints like

```
options: {
  delay: 100, // The number of millseconds to wait before triggering the react event
 breakpoints: { // The different screen resolution breakpoints
   phone: 480,
   bigphone:650
   },
```

I'm then using this like
`<th width="100" data-hide="phone,bigphone" data-sort-ignore="true">Header</th>`
However, this is not working for me!!
What is it i'm missing or doing wrong!

Comment: i think the `width="100"` is your problem

Comment: i tried removing width, nothing changed, still not working!!

Comment: I've been to this [link1](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/288) and [link2](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/165), but i'm still not able to figure it out..

Comment: from the links the problem seems to be fixed for v3 ,try that version

Comment: did you find a fix for this I;ve had the same problem

Comment: @munkee Sorry bro, i couldn't find a way to fix this so i dropped footable. Now what i do is provide `overflow:auto` to my table :(

Comment: custom breakpoints don't work in version 2 unless you edit the javascript file. There are only 2 defaults: "phone" and "tablet". Good luck! This has been driving me crazy for months.